# Is there a way around ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE without purchasing an SSL certificate?

Tags: http, ssl, https

So I am a developer for two sites: domainA.com and domainB.com. domainA.com is pulling in an email feed from domainB.com using the following javascript link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://emailfeed.domainB.com/blah">
```

This was working fine, but I recently had to purchase and install an SSL certificate for domainA.com. After doing that I got a couple errors from referencing a couple apis using http, which I quickly fixed by changing their links to https. However when I try to change the above link to https, I get

```
GET https://emailfeed.domainB.com/blah net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

which I immediately know is because domainB.com does not have an SSL certificate. It seems like I can't access any http resources from an https site. I get why it's set up like this, but it also seems extremely inconvenient since I control both sites so I know both are secure.

So my question is, is there a way around this issue without buying an SSL certificate for domainB.com?

Comment: An SSL *certificate.* There is no such thing as 'an SSL'.

Answer (score 1):

> ... since I control both sites so I know both are secure

SSL/TLS does not protect the security of a site and you can also make no assumptions about the security of a site which is using SSL/TLS. SSL/TLS protects only the transport of the data between the client and the server. This transport might get attacked without attacking the server or client and even if you have full control of the server you usually don't have full control of the network path between client and server.

> GET https://emailfeed.domainB.com/blah net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

This means that the client is not able to verify that it talks to the correct server, i.e. it could also be the wrong server or a man in the middle. Again, this makes no assumptions about the security of the server itself.

> So my question is, is there a way around this issue without buying an SSL certificate for domainB.com?

If you have only a few clients and all of these clients are in your control you could make these clients accept the specific self-signed certificate for the site. If you have more clients or clients you don't control you need a certificate which gets trusted by the clients without adding explicit exceptions. Such certificates are signed by a CA which is trusted by the client. You can get such certificates from a variety of CA and depending on the kind of certificate and the service you expect from the CA they might cost money or they might even be free, like with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way around this without getting an SSL certificate.

However, note that I said *getting* a certificate, not *buying* one. You can get a free SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), no strings attached.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to proxy everything through domainA, so that the GET is for a URL from domainA, for which you have a certificate, and then the backend software on that machine makes the connection over to domainB and forwards the response.